# nancy razor first time setup - route not found 404

Tags: nancy

Steps I took to setup project:

1. created new asp.net project
2. Install-Package Nancy.Viewengines.Razor
3. added Views/hello.cshtml (simple hello world html)
4. added MainModule.cs
5. hit ctrl-F5 (it returns the directory listing)
6. change url to localhost:41915/hello

Then I get 404 resource not found.
What am I missing?

```
// MainModule.cs

namespace MyProj
{
    using Nancy.Routing;
    using Nancy;

    public class MainModule : NancyModule
    {
        public MainModule(IRouteCacheProvider routeCacheProvider)
        {
            Get["/hello"] = parameters => {
                return View["hello.cshtml"];
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the Nancy.Hosting.AspNet package too.

Comment: ack! I assumed Nancy.Viewengines.Razor package would include all dependencies.

Comment: @snoopy no, nancy is hosting agnostic and can run in iis, self hosted, wcf, owin etc so bringing in a hosting package automatically with a view engine would make no sense.